# Cálculo de la volatilidad anualizada

Tags: r

Tengo la tasa de rendimiento anual y me gustaría obtener la volatilidad anualizada.

```
> head(yearly_return, 5)
           .SXQR       .SXTR       .SXNR       .SXMR       .SXAR       .SX3R
[1,] -0.04211651 -0.01692493 -0.13407901 -0.11054265 -0.13658011  0.27697419
[2,] -0.06170831 -0.06020640 -0.27029244 -0.24498356  0.03086915 -0.01268035
[3,] -0.13181676 -0.31916713 -0.37079853 -0.45051590 -0.28119776 -0.11107462
[4,]  0.12010929  0.23596541  0.19548718  0.09116377  0.18582579 -0.02995400
[5,]  0.09574009  0.07114804  0.09357744  0.07972675  0.02328106  0.06988229
           .SX6R      .SXFR       .SXOR       .SXDR       .SX4R        .SXRR
[1,]  0.10468134  0.1599970 -0.04359011  0.26370803  0.05147042 -0.225365403
[2,] -0.07140654 -0.1555470  0.01994745 -0.07791252 -0.13987785 -0.009904841
[3,] -0.23011230 -0.3433740 -0.28950626 -0.28954601 -0.21697798 -0.291441728
[4,]  0.10787296  0.1305620  0.24454257  0.08783802  0.04559812  0.088919239
[5,]  0.28179398  0.2397919  0.24245656  0.02901212  0.15874338  0.125110885
            .SXER      .SXKR      .SX7R       .SX8R       .SXIR      .SXPR
[1,]  0.043774723 -0.3615836  0.1283161 -0.17028728  0.21292564 -0.1806196
[2,] -0.009732258 -0.2833454 -0.0602872 -0.39441865 -0.28494845  0.1871347
[3,] -0.150425114 -0.3655823 -0.2367712 -0.55863189 -0.49789995 -0.1753154
[4,]  0.022473035  0.1512421  0.2105499  0.26432695  0.07890223  0.1914243
[5,]  0.138461912  0.1211539  0.1215245 -0.02500651  0.09043759  0.1280607
```

Los precios diarios provienen de [este archivo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MExW-r0NNGAlMxlQh_tjOscpm6xBiMsfMKRPQykJgr8/edit?usp=sharing) y este código :

```
df <- read.xlsx("Data.xlsx", sheet = "Sector-STOXX600", startRow = 2,colNames = TRUE, detectDates = TRUE, skipEmptyRows = FALSE)
df[2:19] <- data.matrix(df[2:19])
```

Creo que casi lo hice con:

```
volatility_function <- function(x)sqrt(252) * sd(diff(log(x))) * 100
annualized_volatility <- df %>%
  group_by(gr = floor_date(Date, unit = "year"))%>%
  summarize_at(vars(-Date, -gr), volatility_function) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-gr) %>% 
  as.matrix()  
head(annualized_volatility, 5)
```

Sin embargo, hay muchos valores faltantes en la respuesta:

```
> head(annualized_volatility, 5)
        .SXQR    .SXTR    .SXNR    .SXMR    .SXAR    .SX3R    .SX6R    .SXFR
[1,] 22.02142 20.43130 17.13465 40.97723 18.29027 18.04644 14.48501 16.99419
[2,] 25.76975 26.87473       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
[3,] 25.25178 28.91409 24.11453 36.82997 37.22605 20.28364 22.79909 31.74122
[4,] 19.99782 23.64921       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
[5,] 12.40295 14.65185       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
        .SXOR    .SXDR    .SX4R    .SXRR    .SXER    .SXKR    .SX7R    .SX8R
[1,] 16.30835 19.55287 18.35675 16.96180 26.01240 42.23152 18.29375 49.62865
[2,]       NA       NA       NA 16.81732       NA       NA       NA       NA
[3,] 23.35008 26.94605 27.67144 25.93838 31.77843 41.12819 32.13011 52.25582
[4,]       NA       NA       NA 20.59843       NA       NA       NA       NA
[5,]       NA       NA       NA 12.10395       NA       NA       NA       NA
        .SXIR    .SXPR
[1,] 17.17219 23.48967
[2,]       NA       NA
[3,] 45.71421 28.83333
[4,]       NA       NA
[5,]       NA       NA
```

#### Mi intento

Me deshago de las filas con valores faltantes.

```
volatility_function <- function(x)sqrt(252) * sd(diff(log(x))) * 100
annualized_volatility <- df[complete.cases(df), ] %>% # Para deshacerse de las filas con valores faltantes.
  group_by(gr = floor_date(Date, unit = "year"))%>%
  summarize_at(vars(-Date, -gr), volatility_function) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-gr) %>% 
  as.matrix()  
head(annualized_volatility, 5)
```

Y me devuelve:

```
> head(annualized_volatility)
        .SXQR    .SXTR    .SXNR    .SXMR    .SXAR     .SX3R    .SX6R    .SXFR
[1,] 22.02142 20.43130 17.13465 40.97723 18.29027 18.046439 14.48501 16.99419
[2,] 25.83552 26.96622 25.09452 33.39206 30.85724 17.746178 16.42671 27.80582
[3,] 25.25178 28.91409 24.11453 36.82997 37.22605 20.283639 22.79909 31.74122
[4,] 20.07738 23.74381 18.83412 27.63602 30.18198 17.968572 18.78502 19.42008
[5,] 12.40780 14.68115 13.51682 16.64709 17.37418 10.152944 10.50091 11.00480
[6,] 10.38680 11.28891 10.63116 10.78472 14.39485  9.100692 11.62565 10.53404
        .SXOR    .SXDR    .SX4R     .SXRR    .SXER    .SXKR     .SX7R    .SX8R
[1,] 16.30835 19.55287 18.35675 16.961803 26.01240 42.23152 18.293753 49.62865
[2,] 18.38574 21.79742 22.60158 16.857792 28.00532 38.37951 27.417289 57.48731
[3,] 23.35008 26.94605 27.67144 25.938379 31.77843 41.12819 32.130105 52.25582
[4,] 20.16187 21.80619 26.31914 20.631465 22.91296 22.86394 22.374202 34.38963
[5,] 11.83515 12.52007 13.50968 12.125941 14.67853 14.84850 12.219546 26.21946
[6,] 10.96996 10.67187 12.16943  9.789476 16.24038 11.90261  9.993306 15.67066
        .SXIR    .SXPR
[1,] 17.17219 23.48967
[2,] 29.55573 25.81690
[3,] 45.71421 28.83333
[4,] 37.07314 24.29006
[5,] 16.75831 19.40763
[6,] 11.85841 18.42887
```

Comment: Me parece que estás confundido, por lo que veo, estás haciendo: `head(df[complete.cases(df), ])` que te lista el `data.frame` original. No debiera ser `head(annualized_volatility, 5)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tienes un problema en la fórmula de cálculo. Si tienes cotizaciones diarias, no es necesario calcular retornos anuales, puedes utilizar retornos diarios para calcular el desvio diario y después utilizar la fórmula para transformar en [anual](https://www.cuidatudinero.com/13068185/como-anualizar-la-volatilidad).

```
daily_rets=lapply(xts(dData[,-1],order.by = dData$Date),Return.calculate)
daily_sd=sapply(daily_rets,StdDev)
an_volatil=daily_sd*sqrt(252)
rbind(daily_sd,an_volatil)

# > rbind(daily_sd,an_volatil)
#                 .SXQR      .SXTR      .SXNR      .SXMR      .SXAR       .SX3R
# daily_sd   0.01197673 0.01357441 0.01347687 0.01457024 0.02096201 0.009942118
# an_volatil 0.19012470 0.21548709 0.21393862 0.23129541 0.33276161 0.157826237
```

El resultado será el mismo que utilizar directamente la función `sd.annualized`

```
sapply(daily_rets,sd.annualized)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias para la ayuda. Sin embargo cuando me piden que calcule el "rendimiento anualizado", ¿la "volatilidad anualizada" no debería calcularlo año tras año? `annualized return, annualized volatility,`  ¿Eso significa que tengo que hacerlo año tras año? Pensé que eso era lo que estaba haciendo con `annualized_volatility` el cual tiene múltiples lineas para cada anos (a mi parecer, no soy un experto de R)

Comment: Si es necesario mostrar cálculos anuais, podrías usar el mismo código dentro de um función y después dividir el df por cada año. Luego passas cada año de datos a essa función. Buena suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias. Y como puedo hacerlo si tengo coeficientes?